# Error when Apache Zeppelin connects to Apache Flink remote cluster

Tags: apache-flink, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to setup Apache Zeppelin and Apache Flink using docker-compose.

I can get Zeppelin to work well with Flink in **local** mode, when Zeppelin spawns a local Flink cluster, but **not in remote mode** when Zeppelin connects to an existing cluster.

I settled on using **Flink 1.12.0** with Zeppelin as this is the only version I can get working in local mode.

I use the following docker-compose.yml, which is largely inspired by the Flink documentation: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/docker/

```yaml
    version: "2.2"
    services:
      jobmanager:
        image: flink:1.12.0
        ports:
          - "8081:8081"
        command: jobmanager
        environment:
          - |
            FLINK_PROPERTIES=
            jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager        
      taskmanager:
        image: flink:1.12.0
        depends_on:
          - jobmanager
        command: taskmanager
        scale: 1
        environment:
          - |
            FLINK_PROPERTIES=
            jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
            taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2  
      zeppelin:
        image: apache/zeppelin:0.10.1
        hostname: zeppelin
        depends_on:
          - taskmanager
        container_name: zeppelin
        ports:
          - "9080:8080"
          - "9081:8081"
        volumes:
          - /home/administrator/flink/flink-1.12.0:/opt/flink
        environment:
          FLINK_HOME: /opt/flink
```

I use the Zeppelin UI on port 9081 to configure the remote Flink cluster. The parameters are:

```
flink.execution.mode: remote
flink.execution.remote.host: jobmanager
flink.execution.remote.port: 8081
```

I get this error when executing the "Flinks Basic" notebook Batch WordCount cell.

```
    data: org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet[String] = org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet@6adbed6a
    org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: c55932eec9cc32b8df64630be00b2532)
       at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:119 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$22(RestClusterClient.java:602 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:379 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:575 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:943 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:456 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149 undefined)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624 undefined)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748 undefined)
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:147 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:117 undefined)
      ... 19 more
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:116 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:78 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:224 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:217 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:208 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:610 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:89 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:419 undefined)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:286 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:201 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:154 undefined)
       at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26 undefined)
       at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21 undefined)
       at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123 undefined)
       at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122 undefined)
       at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21 undefined)
       at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171 undefined)
       at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172 undefined)
       at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172 undefined)
       at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517 undefined)
       at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515 undefined)
       at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225 undefined)
       at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592 undefined)
       at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561 undefined)
       at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258 undefined)
       at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225 undefined)
       at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235 undefined)
       at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260 undefined)
       at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339 undefined)
       at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979 undefined)
       at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107 undefined)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The initialization of the DataSource's outputs caused an error: Could not read the user code wrapper: org.apache.flink.api.scala.typeutils.CaseClassTypeInfo; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -3156538608383968041, local class serialVersionUID = -8170136754691974512
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.invoke(DataSourceTask.java:110 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:722 undefined)
       at org.apache.flinktime.taskmanager.Task.run.run(Task.java:547 undefined)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748 undefined)
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.CorruptConfigurationException: Could not read the user code wrapper: org.apache.flink.api.scala.typeutils.CaseClassTypeInfo; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -3156538608383968041, local class serialVersionUID = -8170136754691974512
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getStubWrapper(TaskConfig.java:290 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.instantiateUserCode(BatchTask.java:1464 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.SynchronousChainedCombineDriver.setup(SynchronousChainedCombineDriver.java:90 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.ChainedDriver.setup(ChainedDriver.java:91 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.initOutputs(BatchTask.java:1333 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.initOutputs(DataSourceTask.java:317 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.invoke(DataSourceTask.java:107 undefined)
      ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.flink.api.scala.typeutils.CaseClassTypeInfo; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -3156538608383968041, local class serialVersionUID = -8170136754691974512
       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2003 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1850 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2003 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1850 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2160 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503 undefined)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:576 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:562 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:550 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.readObjectFromConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:511 undefined)
       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getStubWrapper(TaskConfig.java:288 undefined)
  ... 9 more
```

### Here is what I tried

- Looked inside Flink's log file for other ports to try instead of 8081. None worked.
- Tried other versions of Fink but got different errors and could not even get Zeppelin to work in local mode.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks,
Michel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get Apache Zeppelin to use a remote instance of Apache Flink by explicitly mentioning the version of Scala (2.11) in the image to pull down.

```
flink:1.14.6-scala_2.11-java11
```

Also, I upgraded to a more recent version of Apache Flink (1.14.6). I understand 1.14.6 is the last version of Flink which ships with Scala 2.11.

Here is the docker-compose.yml that works for me:

```yaml
version: "2.2"
services:
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.14.6-scala_2.11-java11
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager        

  taskmanager:
    image: flink:1.14.6-scala_2.11-java11
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    scale: 1
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2  

  zeppelin:
    image: apache/zeppelin:0.10.1
    hostname: zeppelin
    depends_on:
      - taskmanager
    container_name: zeppelin
    ports:
      - "9080:8080"
      - "9081:8081"
    volumes:
      - /home/administrator/flink/flink-1.14.6:/opt/flink
    environment:
      FLINK_HOME: /opt/flink
```

Apache Zeppelin is accessible on HTTP//<server_ip>:9081 and is configured with these settings:

```
flink.execution.mode    remote
flink.execution.remote.host jobmanager
flink.execution.remote.port 8081
```